# Knockout JS: How to dynamically update <td> count to equal <th> count?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript, ko.observablearray

#### Info:

I'm trying to learn web development with Knockout by building a simple gradebook app. It's still very early in development, but I've hit a road block getting my `<td>`'s in each `<tr>` to match the columns in the `<th>` element. So far, I have no issues adding rows or header columns, but when I attempt to update each row such that it has the same number or columns as the table header, I get weird behaviour.

See an example here:  http://jsbin.com/fehoq/2/edit

It looks like I'm getting new `<td>`'s, but my `<input>` elements are missing, as are their empty string values!

Note:  I generated the javascript using typescript. I don't think that should be an issue though.

#### Relevant Script:

From my Model:

```
addScore = function(score){
   this.scores.push(score);
}
```

From my View Model:

```
updateRows = function(){
    for(var i=1;i<this.students.length;i++){
        while(this.students[i].scores.length<this.assignments.length){
            this.students[i].addScore("");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that assignments is an observable array of "work" objects, and students is an observable array of student objects. "Scores" is also an observable array belonging to each student object.

#### Edit:

It looks like my updateRows() method is accomplishing nothing whatsoever. I do not know where to call it.

Comment: why do you have td in your table header?

Comment: That was a careless mistake. I've updated the markup so that it's a `<th>` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the foreach should be a parent element, since that is not possible in your case you should use the comment notation: http://jsbin.com/wideyeku/2/edit?html,js,output

```html
<thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <!-- ko foreach: assignments -->
            <th><input data-bind="value: workName"/></th>
          <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>    
</thead>
```

**UPDATE**:
http://jsbin.com/wideyeku/4/edit?js,console,output
I found out you had some logical mistakes in your code:

first of all, `this` is variable in javascript, so keep a reference to it in your model:

```
function StudentsViewModel() {
              var self = this;
```

then correct your update rows function:

```
this.updateRows = function () {
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.students(), function(student){
                      while(student.scores().length < self.assignments().length){
                        student.scores.push("");
                      }
                    })
                };
```

never forget that observableArrays are **functions**, and need to be invoked.

Comment: You're right, I have updated my markup to now reflect this. However, my problem still persists; updateRows() does not create new `<td>`'s when I add new `<th>`'s.

Comment: I think there is a logical mistake in there.. I'm working on it :-)

Comment: `undefined is not a function` <-- my console error message.

Comment: Perfect - indeed I did forget that observableArrays are functions.